# Sending json using native javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I want to use native javascript to send a json to php file. Why my $_POST from get-translation.php is empty?

```
var xmlhttp;
json_data = JSON.stringify(a_data);

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
     xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
     xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.open("POST","get-translation.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");

xmlhttp.send(json_data); // json_data is simple json
```

Comment: Why are you calling send() twice? Does get-translation.php work as intended?

Comment: i didn`t see that i was calling twice. $_POST don`t return anything in get-translation.php

Comment: $_POST only works for the standard application/x-www-form-urlencoded content type, not for application/json. Use `$jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$_POST only works for the default content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.
For any other type of data - including JSON - you need to parse the raw input stream.

`file_get_contents('php://input')` will return the raw request body. Since this is JSON, you need to use `json_decode` to parse the json data into an associative array.

```
$jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the JSON data a string:

```
json_data = JSON.stringify(json_data);
```